# Does Spring batch have a Redis ItemReader in the roadmap?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am looking for reading from a Redis LIST to read Spring XD failed messages and process them again through batch workflow. Is there a Redis ItemReader available? I checked the GitHub repo for batch and could not locate one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer to the batch question, but you can do it with a pair of Spring Integration inbound and outbound queue channel adapters to move the data from the `ERROR:` list back to the bus LIST>

Comment: @SathiyaS - Did you able to implement this ?